# C++ write and read a file in binary mode

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

I want to create a binary file in `/dev/shm/uploaded` and open a file in binary mode and write data into it.

```
    std::string string_path = "/dev/shm/uploaded/";
    std::string filename = "download_file.out";
    std::string tmpStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    createFile(string_path, filename); 

    bool createFile(std::string &string_path, std::string &filename) {
        std::string command_string = "mkdir -p ";
        command_string.append(string_path);
        std::cout << command_string << std::endl;
        int check = system(command_string.c_str());
        if(-1 == check) {
           return false;
        }
        std::ofstream outfile(string_path + filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        if(outfile.is_open()) {
          for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
              outfile << tmpStr;
          }
        }
        outfile.close();
        return true;
    }
```

I suspect that using `<<` operator I am writing the data in text mode, rather than in binary mode.
I want to write the data in binary mode.

I was looking at [binary read and write](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2011/06/write-and-read-binary-files-in-c.html)

It has a function as follows

```
template<>
std::ostream& binary_write_string(std::ofstream& stream, const std::string& value){
    return stream->write(value.c_str(), value.length());
}
```

In this function what does a templated function without `typename` or `class` mean? Is this the correct approach.

Comment: `In this function what does a templated function without typename or class mean?` - It's a [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Comment: Isn't the main difference between text and binary mode the newline conversion?

Comment: A string represents a text, and it doesn't matter whether you write in binary mode or not. it would still appear as a human readable text. Try writing a number if you want to see the difference.

Comment: `binary_write_string` should be `binary_write`, the former won't compile as it is a specialisation of a function that doesn't exist

Comment: @Azad That is actually not true. It depends on the encoding and also endianess that can result in different outputs between binary and text mode.

Comment: “correct approach” - it is a solution. The code you shown is just a part of the solution. The template parameters are missing because it is a specialization of a function you did not shown. It won’t compile.

Answer (score 1):

As Botje suggests, the main difference between text and binary mode is the newline conversion. You can try the following code and see the output.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string tmpStr = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\n";

    ofstream outbinfile("output_binary.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        outbinfile << tmpStr;
    outbinfile.close();

    ofstream outfile("output.txt", std::ios::out);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        outfile << tmpStr;
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

`output_binary.txt` is 132 bytes, as expected. But `output.txt` is 135 bytes in Windows. Because for newline, it writes out `\r\n` actually.[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation)

Answer (score 1):

1. The difference between `xfstream( fn, ios::text )` and `xfstream( fn, ios::binary )` (where x is `i` or `o`) is **how the end-of-line is inserted/extracted**.

   - For a text stream `is << '\n'` will insert (depending on OS) `\n\r`. On extracting, the sequence will be **translated back to `\n`**.
   - For a binary stream, **what you insert/extract is what you write/read**.
2. Opening a stream in binary mode and writing/reading binary data to/from it are different things. When you use the insertion/extraction operators (`<<` & `>>`) you write/read **formatted data (similar to `printf` in c)**:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   using namespace std;
   //...
   cout << setfill( '~' ) << setw( 2 ) << 2; // outputs "~2"
   ```
3. If you want to **write/read the actual bytes** (the 4 bytes of a 32bit integer, for instance, not its human readable form) you must use `ostream::write`/`istream::read`. c++ wont stop you from using these functions with a text stream. It is your responsibility to combine them correctly.
4. In c++, template functions may be **specialized**: exhibit different behavior for specific template signatures. What **you missed from the referred link is the unspecialized version of the function**.

   ```
   template<typename T> void f( T )
   {
     cout << "unspecialized\n";
   }

   template<> void f( const char* s )
   {
     cout << "specialized\n";
   }
   //...
   f( 0 ); // prints "unspecialized"
   f( 'c' ); // prints "unspecialized"
   f( "" ); // prints "specialized"
   ```